# Programmatically execute textFieldShouldReturn from inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

What is the way programmatically execute (simulate) **func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool** function from the input accessory view.

MyCustomInputView have DONE button. I want that **func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool** will be triggered for MyTextField delegates when DONE button pressed. What is the way to achieve it?

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {

    func setup() {
       let myCustomInputView = MyCustomInputView()
       self.inputAccessoryView = myCustomInputView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did extended functionality that MyCustomInputView will have UITextField.

```
class MyCustomInputView: UIView {
    var textField: UITextField?

    @IBAction func didClickReturnButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if let textField = textField, let textFieldDelegate = textField?.delegate {
            if textFieldDelegate.textFieldShouldReturn!(textField) {
                textField.endEditing(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```